# Jquery :invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

i am having trouble with jquery code of the "jquery_token_inpuy"

```
return template.replace(new RegExp(
    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + value + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"
), highlight_term(value, term));
```

i have this error : SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: / Nothing to repeat.

What is the problem?

Comment: Well, your regular expression is invalid... why don't you print it out before sending it into new RegExp and let us have a look...

Comment: What's in the variable "value"

Comment: Also, can you tell us what pattern your are trying to match?  Preferably with some sample data (valid and invalid matches).

Comment: this code is from :http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: when i try to find "c++" from the search field, it doesn't find it. it has a problem with special characters

Comment: Well in a regular expression "c++" is not going to be valid.  You can't just shove a plain string in the middle of a regular expression and expect it to work all the time. The `+` characters are special in this case, so they have to be quoted.

Comment: so what is the solution to let me find words containing ++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a routine to "quote" all the meta-characters. Something like this would be a start:

```
function regexSanitize( str ) {
  return str.replace(/([.+*?:\[\](){}|\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

then:

```
return template.replace(
  new RegExp(
    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + 
    regexSanitize(value) + 
    ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"), 
  highlight_term(value, term)
);
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. But is the function regexSanitize complete and tested?

Comment: @user3242743 it's tested a little bit. It should work for the meta-characters it looks for, but the underlying problem is kind-of complicated.

Comment: Your function worked for typing "c+", but if i type "c++" an exception is raised. What can be the problem?

Comment: @user3242743 are you sure you included the "g" at the end of the regular expression in the "regexSanitize" function?

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(c++)(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: if i type c+ it is ok , the autocompletion works, but if i type c++ it  does'nt work, it raises the exception that i wrote in the last comment

Comment: @user3242743 did you change your code so that you call that function I supplied in my answer?

Comment: sure,that's what i have now : a =template.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +  regexSanitize(value) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"),

Comment: I don't get any errors when I do that with your RegExp call, and with "value" being "c++".  Make sure that the return value from "regexSanitize" looks like "c\+\+"

Comment: thanks very much "Pointy", it seemed that i needed to add a regexSanitize in anothe function, that inserts a string insid a regex. thanks a lot!